# NullPointerException getSupportFragmentManager() with Facebook onSessionStateChange

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, facebook-login, fragmentmanager, facebook-sdk-3.1

I am using the `Facebook SDK` to do a FB login. Sometimes I receive a random `NullPointerException` when returning from the Facebook login.

The NPE is on my line:

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
```

My FB login is in a single `Fragment`. When the user logs into FB and is successful, it changes the `Fragment` to another. **Why am I getting this NPE?**

```
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) { 
        Log.i("Facebook", "Logged In");
        mPrefs.setFbLoggedIn(true);

        Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                if (response.getError() == null) {
                    FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right_to_left, R.anim.slide_out_right_to_left, 
                            R.anim.slide_in_right_to_left, R.anim.slide_out_right_to_left);
                    ft.remove(fm.findFragmentById(R.id.container));
                    ft.add(R.id.container, LoadingFragment.newInstance(), "loadingFragment");
                    ft.commit();

                    String fbId = "";
                    try { fbId = user.getId(); }
                    catch (NullPointerException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

                    String fullName = "";
                    try { fullName = user.getName(); }
                    catch (NullPointerException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

                    String email = "";
                    try { email = user.getProperty("email").toString(); }
                    catch (NullPointerException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

                    String gender = "";
                    try { gender = user.getProperty("gender").toString(); }
                    catch (NullPointerException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

                    String pictureUrl = "";
                    try { pictureUrl = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + user.getId() + "/picture?type=large"; }
                    catch (NullPointerException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

                    String birthdate = "";
                    try {
                        if (user.getBirthday() != null && !user.getBirthday().isEmpty()) {
                            try { 
                                DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse(user.getBirthday(), DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy"));
                                DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ")
                                        .withZone(DateTimeZone.getDefault());
                                birthdate = formatter.print(dateTime);
                            } 
                            catch (IllegalArgumentException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (NullPointerException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

                    User u = new User(fbId, email, fullName, gender, birthdate, pictureUrl);
                    FacebookMethods.writeFbInfo(getActivity(), u);

                    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).connectToServer();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), response.getError().getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }).executeAsync();
    } 
    else if (state.isClosed()) { 
        Log.i("Facebook", "Logged Out"); 
        mPrefs.setFbLoggedIn(false);
    }
}
```

**Stacktrace (not full, but the important lines)**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.walintukai.lfdate.LoginFragment$2.onCompleted(LoginFragment.java:278)
   at com.facebook.Request$1.onCompleted(Request.java:303)
   at com.facebook.Request$4.run(Request.java:1726)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5050)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: If it's on this line, it means `getActivity()` is null. It will happend if your `onCompleted` method gets called after your Activity being stopped/finished. Paste your full StackTrace

Comment: @SimonMarquis I don't have the full stacktrace, but here are the first set of lines. Is this enough?

Comment: definitively, your Activity is stopped. It will happend every time you press the back button too early. Your activity is stopped, onCompleted is called, getActivity() is null -> NullPointerException

Comment: @SimonMarquis Explained very well! Thank you. So, to reiterate, the user is logging in with FB, and then when returning to my app, they pressed the back button too early before `onCompleted` was called? What would be the best way to put in an error check for this?

Comment: Simply return from your method if getActivity() returns null

Comment: @SimonMarquis Makes perfect sense! Thanks for the help! Please make an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getActivity()` here can return null if the Activity was stopped (back button, home, recent, ...).

To avoid error simply stop the method early:

```
   Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
            if (getActivity() == null) {
                // The activity was stopped
                return;
            }
            // else we can continue 
            // ...
        }
    });
```